# Best way to run SQL Server in Docker in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker

Trying to find article or solution page in Azure but I am not successful yet.

The title is pretty much self explanatory. I am looking for a known best practice or solution with steps to follow to run docker with SQL Server in Azure.

I have Docker with SQL Server Express, Docker for Windows, running locally and my expectation is simply deploying this to Azure.

Based on my short experience with Azure, I probably need to set up some Azure service where I can deploy my docker image and run, not sure what that Azure product should be (probably more of Azure Container than Azure SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, given your requirement of windows containers (why?), you can use either Azure Container Instances (but be mindful of base images they support) or AKS engine. I'd discard webapps.

Comment: It doesn't have to be windows containers.. Is there a reason you prefer Linux container?

Comment: yeah, windows containers are a bit bad at this point in time, tbh. say, AKS doesnt support hybrid\windows clusters. back in 1803 days, kubernetes clusters with windows nodes were extremely fragile\inconsistent, 5gb base images, etc

Comment: What would be the better option if I use docker for Linux? Or you meant more various options if I used Linux container..

Comment: well, the question is hard to answer since I dont know all your requirements, but I'd go for AKS (ACI is too expensive)